# Emacs search words with underscores not considered as word boundaries

Tags: regex, search, emacs, word-boundary

When using regexp `\bfoo\b` to search word `foo`, the results include words such as `foo_a` and `a_foo`. How to exclude these words from the results? i.e., how to ask emacs not to consider underscores as word boundaries.

Answer (score 5):

I finally found a solution:

By default, the underscore _ is not a word-constituent character (in other words, it is a word-boundary).
We can define the underscore as a word-constituent character via adding

```
 (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w")
```

in `.emacs` file.

To make this work in a major mode, we need to add this definition to the mode hook:

```
(defun yjf90 () (modify-syntax-entry ?_ "w"))
(add-hook 'f90-mode-hook 'yjf90)
```

See [this](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/56421/how-to-modify-syntax-entry-for-a-major-mode)

Update:

More accurately, we should distinguish between word boundary and symbol boundary. The former is `\b`, the latter: the start and end of a symbol are `\_<` and `\_>`, respectively (this is so awkward that I am not aware of its existence after using Emacs for many years). Most programming languages consider the underscore as a part of a symbol, so the straightforward solution to the question is to use `\_<foo\_>` as the searching regexp.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use EMAC, but in Notepad++ or in python `\bfoo\b` should give you the required result.
But since it is not working out for you, this should work: `\b(?<!_)foo(?!_)\b`

```
(?<!_) - negative look behind to ensure that _ does not precede
(?!_) - negative look ahead to ensure that _ does not follow
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/nda58j/2)

Comment: tested, not work in Emacs, thanks